# Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns (9)

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

Okay, this one is driving me nuts.

I'm trying to create a jQuery Datatable and keep getting the error:
*DataTables warning (table id = 'properties'): Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns (9)*

I have a table set up with 9 columns (i.e. 9 `<th>` blocks in the html)

The Javascript appears to look alright (though it would help if someone would verify that for sure):

```
$tableProperties = $('#properties').dataTable({
    sDom: '<"dataTables_header"<"dataTables_toolbar">rl>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
    oLanguage: { sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_ lines", sInfo: "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ lines" },
    iDisplayLength: <%: ShusterConnect.ConfigurationSettings.MgtPropertiesPerPage %>,
    aLengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
    bPaginate: true,
    sPaginationType: "listbox",
    bLengthChange: true,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: true,
    bAutoWidth: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: true,
    sAjaxSource: "/property/QueryAllProperties",
    aaSorting: [[ 5, "asc" ]], // default sorting column is Management Company
    fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.post(sSource, aoData, fnCallback);
    },
    fnRowCallback: function (tr, record, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $('td:eq(7)', tr).html(renderActionTemplate(record[7], $('td:eq(4)', tr).text()));
        $('td:eq(7)', tr).css("white-space", "nowrap");
        if ($('td:eq(4)', tr).text() != "Yes")
            $(tr).css("background-color", "#c0c0c0");
        return tr;
    },
    aoColumns: [
        { "mDataProp": "ShusterPropertyID" },
        { "mDataProp": "ShusterCustomerID" },
        { "mDataProp": "BEPropertyID" },
        { "mDataProp": "BEUserName" },
        { "mDataProp": "IsManagementCompany" },
        { "mDataProp": "ManagementCompany" },
        { "mDataProp": "MappingFileType" },
        { "mDataProp": "Action", "bSortable": false},  // action
        { "mDataProp": "ParentId" } //Parent Id 
    ],
    });
});
```

And my JSON is returning an aaData set with 9 values for each record:
`{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":147,"iTotalDisplayRecords":147,"aaData":[{"ShusterCustomerId":"1057","ShusterPropertyId":"DEV","BEPropertyId":"4368058011","BEUserName":"Devon Oaks","IsManagementCompany":"","ManagementCompany":"Eliza Jennings Senior Care Network","MappingFileType":"Default","Action":"57","ParentId":""},{"ShusterCustomerId":"1058","ShusterPropertyId":"ELIZA","BEPropertyId":"4368056561","BEUserName":"Eliza Jennings Home","IsManagementCompany":"","ManagementCompany":"Eliza Jennings Senior Care Network","MappingFileType":"Default","Action":"58","ParentId":""}, ... {"ShusterCustomerId":"1168","ShusterPropertyId":"WESC","BEPropertyId":"3008297838","BEUserName":"Wesley Court Methodist Retirement Community","IsManagementCompany":"","ManagementCompany":"Sears Methodist Retirement System","MappingFileType":"PathLinks","Action":"243","ParentId":"232"}]}`

So... What the heck is going on? Have I missed something vital? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I did spend an hour searching the interwebs (and StackOverflow), but was unable to find anything that would point to the problem...

Comment: Just for clarity, I'm using jQuery 1.7.6

Comment: ShusterPropertyID doesn't equal ShusterPropertyId - you have two others like that as well where your Json Data doesn't match aaColumns. I believe aaDataProp and the aaColumns have to match up with the right case. ShusterCustomerID and BEPropertyID are the other ones.

Comment: Please share the table html, and echo the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json data format should be like this:
{"sEcho":17,"iTotalRecords":35,"iTotalDisplayRecords":35,"aaData":[["2012-12-01","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-26","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-19","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-21","1"],["2012-12-27","1"],["2012-12-25","1"],["2012-12-26","1"],["2012-01-03","1"],["2012-11-23","1"],["2012-12-02","1"],["2012-11-22","1"],["2012-12-24","1"],["2012-11-14","1"],["2012-11-22","1"],["2012-11-23","1"],["2012-11-22","1"],["2012-11-22","1"],["2012-11-26","1"],["2012-12-20","1"],["2012-12-17","1"],["2012-12-21","1"],["2012-12-12","1"]]}

So to get this formate of data, do this: 
    $rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);
     $rResult = $rResult->result_array();

```
foreach ($rResult as $aRow) {
     $row = array();


 foreach ( $aRow as $key => $val ) {





  $row[] = $val;
}

      $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode( $output );
```